# How to insert another variable into string with a Space? C#

Tags: c#, string, text

I know this is a very stupid and elementary question, but I really have no idea on other ways to accomplish this.

Now I know I can insert spaces within the text like my example below.

```
int num = some numerical value;
status.Text = "Successfully Deleted"+ " " + num + " " + "Files";
```

However, I'm wondering is there a neater way to do this.  I always done it this way, but I'm wondering whether there's an easier/neater way to it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using String class:

```
int num = 5;
status.Text = String.Format("Successfully Deleted {0} Files", num);
```

Using StringBuilder class:

```
int num = 5;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendFormat("Successfully Deleted {0} Files", num);
status.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: status.Text = String.Format("Successfully Deleted {0} File{1}", num, (num>1)?"s":"");

Comment: Wow, that was easy, thanks.  I faintly remembered it had something to do with the {0}.  Thanks.

Comment: @Movieboy if this answer helped you - don't be shy to accept it http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: Why use a stringbuilder here?  It's not adding anything.

Comment: For the sake of different flavors.

Answer (score 0):

More options:

```
status.Text = "Successfully Deleted " + num + " Files";
```

Or:

```
public static string SurroundWithSpaces(this object o)
{
    return " " + o + " ";
}
status.Text = "Successfully Deleted" + num.SurroundWithSpaces() + "Files";
```